# Get random double number from [0,1] in C++

Tags: c++, random

I want to generate random double number `x`, where: `0 <= x <= 1`:

```
double x = ((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX));
```

Is this the correct way of getting random double number from [0,1] ?

Comment: Yes it seems to be correct.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal: Thanks! But will it give me 0 as well as 1 for 100%? Are you sure?

Comment: Remove half of the parentheses. They're redundant.

Comment: Someone might find this more useful: for range [min, max] you could use: (((double)rand()*(max - min) / RAND_MAX) + min)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, since `std::rand()` returns both `0` and `RAND_MAX`. However, if you can use C++11, you can use `std::uniform_real_distribution` instead.

Also don't forget to initialize your random number generator, otherwise you will get the same sequence in every execution. If you use `std::rand`, `std::srand( std::time(0) )` is almost always sufficient.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cant use c++11 :(

Comment: @nullpointer: Then your original approach is perfectly valid and will work.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Some parentheses are superfluous though.

And it depends on your application whether you can trust your systems rand(3) function. For serious Monte-Carlo simulations you will need a well-documented random-number generator from a numerical library.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, I believe it will give you 0 and 1 in a random sequence when generated subsequently. But be sure to initialize the random number generator function to avoid getting same sequence again and again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes but I recommend to cast RAND_MAX to double too:

```
double r = ((double)rand() / (double)(RAND_MAX));
```

Although sometimes unnecessary, the compiler may automatically cast operators to another type depending on target and source variable types. For e.g:

3.5 / 2 may be equal to 1 and not 1.75 because the divisor is an integer and to avoid this you must do:

3.5 / 2.0 or 3.5 / (double)2

Comment: No, `3.5/2` will never be `1`; integers are always promoted to floating-point, not the other way round. Making the promotion explicit might make the code slightly easier to follow if you're unfamiliar with the promotion rules, but it's never necessary and won't change the behaviour unless you get it wrong.

Comment: Well... may be and old buggy compiler that didn't respect the rules and I got that stigma from a long time :)

Answer (score 1):

If you were looking for a random double this is how I achieved it.

If you are looking for it in a function I can edit this post.

rand() is included within stdlib.h

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    { 
        double num;
        double max;

        srand(time(NULL));

        cout << "Enter a number.";
        cin >> max;

        num = (((double)rand()*(max) / RAND_MAX) - max) *(-1);

        cout << num;


    }
```

Comment: ((double)rand()*(max) / RAND_MAX) has the exact same effect that. However generating numbers in range [min, max] you could use: (((double)rand()*(max - min) / RAND_MAX) + min)